# PHPUnit test class can't extend another class

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

Currently, I have a base Test Class, where my tests should extend:

```
<?php
namespace BlaBla;
class BasicTestCase extends UnitTest {
    public function testPage()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(True);
    }
}
```

And there in my test class:

```
<?php
use BlaBla\BasicTestCase;
class BasicTest extends BasicTestCase {
}
```

My problem is that if I run phpunit and I want to test the `BasicTest`, always I get the error `BasicTestCase class not found`.
After searching, I understood that phpunit doesn't use composer, but I couldn't resolve this conflict.

### Update:

Using `require_once`, or `composer dump-autload` just produce the same error (class Base not found).
Also giving a namespace for the class, didn't solve the problem (always same error).

Here the phpunit.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="phpunit.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
     <testsuite name="Core Test Suite">
        <directory>./vendor/ipo/prodis-core/tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite_testing"/>
</php>
```

The composer.json is so long, so I added here the import:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
      "tests/AppTestCase.php",
      "tests/AppTestCaseClassic.php",
      "vendor/ipo/prodis-core/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

For the structure, I added the second class `BasicTest`, under the folder tests of Laravel, under `Services\Client\Testing`.

What I noticed is that phpunit always searchs for `Base class` in the same location of `BasicTest`.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: You could simply `require_once` your other source file.

Comment: @J.Doe `composer dump-autoload` doesn't help

Comment: @NigelRen also `require_once` doesn't help

Comment: Please if you are facing an autoload issue, share your `composer.json`, your `phpunit.xml` and your tests directories structure so we can recommend you a way to fix this

Comment: Add a namespace to the second file. That's why it can't find the correct file to extend.

Comment: *doesn't help* isn't very informative and makes it difficult to provide more help.

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: is there anything missed?

Answer (score 1):

```
bootstrap="phpunit.php"
```

This line means that PHPUnit will include `phpunit.php` file (from root of the project) before running tests - you should include autoloader inside of it:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// rest of tests bootstrap
```

Or if you don't need any additional bootstrap, you may include autoloader directly as bootstrap file in `phpunit.xml`:

```
bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
```

---

Separate thing is autoloading rules. It is hard to say what is happening in your case, because you didn't share your files stricture. But if you're using namespaces for tests base classes, you can just register regular `psr-4` autoloading rules for these classes:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "BlaBla\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

And then place your `BasicTestCase` class definition in `tests/BasicTestCase.php`.

Comment: This is still causing class not found in phpunit even with the additional `autoload-dev` entries and `bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"`